# Have you a favourite film about sound?

Tags: film, documentary, recording

There's numerous question on here about favourite examples of sound usage in a film, but what's everyone's favourite film *about* sound? I know it's a limited genre, but worthwhile compiling a list for everyone to draw from!

Last week, I got the opportunity to go to the premiere here in Dublin of the film *Silence* by Pat Collins. It's a docu-drama of sorts, about a sound recordist returning home to Ireland to record natural ambiance away from any man made noise.
It is hauntingly beautiful, with amazing cinematography and a wonderfully philosophical meditation on silence and the effect it has on people.

Site here: http://silencefilm.ie/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Soundtracker - A Portrait Of Gordon Hempton](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROWl0eh9BLo)

[youtube]ROWl0eh9BLo[/youtube]

The guy is a legend!

Comment: I still haven't been able to see this one. Probably just going to have to buy it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that! Just noticed its available on iTunes so will get around to watching that soon.

Answer (score 3):

Plus one for Touch the Sound.

There's a great old newsreel called "Back of the Mike" which shows a radio play performance in action, complete with live sound effects performance. You can watch it [here](http://www.archive.org/details/Backofth1938).

I also dig "Fog City Mavericks" a documentary about Bay Area Filmmakers (Coppola, Lucas etc.) and how they influenced the cinema world, including film sound. You can watch the entire doc [here](http://www.hulu.com/watch/216711/fog-city-mavericks).

There are also great docs about Theramin and Moog out there which are worth a watch if you're interested in pioneers of electronic sound.

Comment: +1000000 for Fog City Mavericks. I was born north of San Fran in a city called Corte Madeira. Fell in love with this flick - it's free on Hulu but I bought it off iTunes for $2.

Comment: For non American's the director has put it on Vimeo himself: http://vimeo.com/12565608

Answer (score 2):

Touch the Sound. It's a documentary about Evelyn Glennie, a deaf percussionist (and an amazing one at that). The first 17=20 minutes is primarily sound montage...there's some dialog in that stretch, but it's very sparse.

It's a must watch for any sound editor/designer/mixer, in my humble opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Am watching it now, awesome stuff. The film editor also did a great job btw, the scene in the railway station is so exciting!

Comment: Just finished watching, beautifully captured and made. I really loved the scene where she was teaching the deaf girl, very moving. And the credits roll was also great. 

Answer (score 1):

Hands down "Modern Romance"

The famous "space floor" scene -

http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-4531705519963169998

Comment: loved that!! :)

Comment: "You saved the picture..." classic.

Answer (score 1):

What about the film *Blow out*. Havent actually watched it yet but the main character is a sound recordist who accidently records the sound of a murder! chilling stuff...

Comment: Not just a main character, but John Travolta! 

Answer (score 0):

I was totally blown away by *Trimpin, the sound of invention*.

[youtube]ahQKsW0LHEA[/youtube]

If you've not seen it, you must!

Answer (score 0):

There was quite an intersting one I saw recently about Pierre Henry which can still be found on Youtube:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uVCYL8zVBk

Worth a look especially if you're into your music concrete ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tim Prebble noted on his blog the movie "Diva". I watched it and liked it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

My favourite movie scene is in **Sneakers** - [When Whistler is navigating by sound.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KuIheGaiFLM)

Answer (score 0):

Well quite literally "The Sound of Noise" is also a great film!

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1278449/

Great question!